# Multiple parameters on cascade function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass more then one parameter in a cascade function:

```
// Cascade function
(function ($) {
    $.fn.cascade = function (options) {
        var defaults = {};
        var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).change(function () {
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                if (selectedValue == '') {
                    opts.childSelect.empty();
                    return;
                }
                var params = {};
                params[opts.paramName] = selectedValue;
                $.post(opts.url, params, function (items) {
                    opts.childSelect.empty();
                    if (opts.firstOption != "")
                        opts.childSelect.append(
                            $('<option/>')
                                .attr('value', '')
                                .text(opts.firstOption));
                    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                        opts.childSelect.append(
                            $('<option/>')
                                .attr('value', item.Id)
                                .text(item.Name)
                        );
                    });
                    if (typeof (opts.callback) == "function") { opts.callback(); }
                });
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

In the call, I need to pass the makeId and a categoryId value:

```
// bind cascade Make dropdown
$("#Make_Id").cascade({
    url: "/Ad/ListModelByCategoryByMake",
    paramName: "makeId",
    firstOption: 'Selecione o Modelo...',
    childSelect: $("#Model_Id")
});
```

The call is made by post, so how can I call the cascade function with two parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Function:

```
$.fn.cascade = function (options, param2) {
    /// ....
}
```

call:

```
$("#Make_Id").cascade({
    url: "/Ad/ListModelByCategoryByMake", // is better to use @Url.Action() helper here
    paramName: "makeId",
    firstOption: 'Selecione o Modelo...',
    childSelect: $("#Model_Id")
}, 'your_second_param');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. How do you pass the param value? I can't put the Url.Action because the code is in an external JS file.

Comment: Call with $("selector").cascade({ // your current options}, param2);

Comment: Ans where do I set the parameter's name?